# Check Login on Shut Down

Tags: android, android-preferences

I have two different options to start my app.

1. Manually start it by clicking the app icon
2. Using a NFC Tag

For the first option i start a login activity because the user has to login first.
he can store the login informations for an automatic login at the next start or 
he can just login once and dont save the login data.

For the second option the NFCActivity also needs to check if the user is logged
in or not and that is the problem because the user can also start the NFCActivity
when he is logged in the main menu. If the user now didnt save the login data the 
user has to login over and over again everytime a Tag is triggering the NFCActivity
to start.

What i need is a possibility to check if the user is logged in for the current session
WITHOUT storing the login in the sharedPreferences.

Is there a smart way to do that or do i have to implement some kind of singleton.

Comment: please be specific with your question

Answer (score 0):

You shoud save data immediatelly after a successful login occures. And vice versa, you should delete saved data in case of login failure.

So, you'll react immediatelly on your event, and you will not need to monitor system shutdown event.

Comment: But the problem is that i per default start my mainactivity and the mainactivity checks if the user is logged in or not. so if i perform a login without storing the login and redirect to my mainactivity i come into an endless loop of loging in. does that mean i have to declare my login as the main activity?

Comment: I think, you can store login (or\and credentials\keys needed) somewhere in prefs\db - to be able to log in without asking a user.

And your application must do nothing and notify the user, if it is unable to log in ;-)

Answer (score 0):

you can make flag and store it in the shared preferences when user logs in make it true and on log out edit it to false when getting this value from shared preferences return a default value as false if nothing is found in this way you can check if the user is logged in or not .

Comment: There is still a remaining problem. my app can also be started using nfc tag. if the user is not logged in he has to login first. so if i manually start my app, perform a login and do NOT sotre the login, the user has to login again when he places the nfc tag even if he is already in the main menu.